# Generating triplets of integers

Tags: java, algorithm

We have 3 positive integers a, b, and c where a + b + c = k, where k is any positive integer.

Is there an optimal way to iterate through the possible configurations of these three integers?

Any pseudocode or Java code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. Besides that: Aren't there any restrictions on a, b and c?

Comment: This isn't homework, it's for a TopCoder problem. If you're interested, here's the link: http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=54&rd=3000

Comment: If you know about only K, Then there is no way to find out a,b,c value. If u know any restriction on that three value then we have some logic.

Comment: Have you done some tests/research, or are you just expecting to find someone nice enough to do all the job for you?

Comment: "Positive" is ambiguous, you need to specify if 0 is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No choice, you have to run through two nested loops:

Assuming that `0<=a,b,c` and that (2,1,1) is the same triplet as (1,1,2) (there are permutationally equivalent), you can add the constraints `a<=b<=c`

```
for(int a=0; a<=k/3; a++) { // a <= b <= c -> 3a <= k
    for(int b=a; b<=(k-a)/2; b++) { // b <= c -> 2b <= k-a
        c = k-a-b;
        //Do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: "No choice": it is also possible to solve this with a single loop by "packing" (a, b) as a single integer and "unpacking" in the loop. Admittedly, this would be an inefficient solution, but this alternative exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two loops for `a` and `b`, however you don't need to iterate over `c` as it can be  calculated.  Also, if order doesn't matter you can assume that `a >= b >= c` which will further reduce the combinations you need to explore.

Note: most of these sort of problems are mathematical, rather than programming challenges.  You need to think of an elegant maths solution before coding it.

Answer (score 1):

The set of triplets `(a,b,c)` such that `a+b+c=k` defines a plane in 3D space, i.e. a 2D entity. For a given `k`, there are exactly `(k+1)(k+2)/2` solutions in positive integers. This expression is `O(k^2)`, showing that a double loop will do.

```
for a= 0 to k
  for b= 0 to k-a
    c= k-a-b
    ...
```

This solution assumes that

- 0 is allowed;
- the order matters, f.i. (1, 2, 3) and (2, 1, 3) are two distinct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I got in out of curiosity. It was fun to get this solution for the problem you posted. You missed the important criteria, that the three numbers have to be distinct and that no pair of the three integers has a common factor greater than 1.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}

public static int pairwisePrimes(int k) {
    int numWays = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < k; a++) {
        for (int b = a + 1; b < k; b++) {
            for (int c = b + 1; c < k; c++) {
                if ((a + b + c == k) && gcd(a, b) == 1 && gcd(a, c) == 1 && gcd(b, c) == 1) {
                    System.out.println("" + a + "+" + b + "+" + c);
                    numWays++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return numWays;
}
```

Comment: I already had a method that checked for the three-way relative primality, so for me it was a matter of iterating through the appropriate integers and putting the triplets to the test. The fact that the three integers have to be distinct doesn't really matter, because the only pair that would have two common numbers are 1, 1 and k, so I just subtracted one to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, given that only 40 values need to be supported, the best solution to the TopCoder problem is a lookup in a precomputed vector. Nothing can beat that (it is both ultrafast and ultracompact):

```
int Table[41]= { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 1, 7, 3, 7, 3, 14, 3, 15, 6, 14, 6, 25, 6, 22, 10, 25, 9, 42, 8, 34, 15, 37, 15, 53, 13, 48, 22, 53 };

return Table[Num];
```

The table can be computed as *inefficiently* as desired (I used a straightforward Python script).

```
import fractions

for k in range(40 + 1):
    T= 0
    for a in range(1, k + 1):
        for b in range(1, k + 1):
            for c in range(1, k + 1):
                if a < b and b < c and a + b + c == k and fractions.gcd(a, b) == 1 and fractions.gcd(b, c) == 1 and fractions.gcd(c, a) == 1:
                    T+= 1
    print T
```

Comment: I'd be curious to see what TopCoder considered the best solution.